# how to save the image name in the database so that you can view it later?

Tags: php, database, laravel

[here the user transfers the photo from the device to the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1OaV.png)
***it is necessary that when registering a user he entered a photo and this photo could be viewed by the administrator in the admin area***

**web.php**

```php
Route::post('/head', 'ImageController@upload')->name('image.upload');
```

**ImageController.php**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $path = $request - file('image')->store('upload', 'public');
        return view('default',['path'=> $path]);
    }
}
```

(php artisan storage:link) *entered*

**input form**

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="ydostak" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Фото удостоверение с двух сторон') }}</label>
    <form action{{ route('image.upload')}}="" method="post" accept-charset="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" name="image">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**withdrawal form**

```html
@isset ($path)
    <img class="img-fluid" scr="{{asset('/storage/'. $path)}}" alt="">
@endisset
```

Comment: What is your question? Did you get any errors or something else?

Comment: ***goes error***The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public function upload(Request $request)
{

    $user  = new user ;

    if($request->hasFile('image')){
      $image = $request->file('image');
      $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
      Image::make($image)->resize(300, 300)->save( storage_path('/uploads/' . $filename ) );
      $user->image = $filename;
      $user->save();
    };

  $user->save();

  return redirect()->route('user.index')
    ->with('success','User created successfully');
   }
```

Comment: ***goes error***The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

Your form tag is incorrectly formed:

```
<form action{{ route('image.upload')}}="" method="post" accept-charset="multipart/form-data">
```

You are not assigning anything to the `action` as what you have isn't the `action` attribute. You have something like this:

```
<form actionhttp://yoursite/head="" ...>
```

Which isn't the `action` attribute. You want:

```
<form action="{{ route('image.upload') }}" ...>
```

Which will give you something like:

```
<form action="http://youriste/head" ...>
```

Once you fix that you can move onto actually dealing with your Controller method.